# LaravelとPHPのバージョンについて

Tags: php, laravel, composer

こんにちは、閲覧ありがとうございます.
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、どうぞよろしくお願い致します.

現在`Laravel`と`PHP`について学習しております.
諸事情により`PHP5.6`をつかって`Laravel`のプロジェクトを作成したいのですが、コマンドプロンプトから`Laravel new プロジェクト名`とコマンドを打ちLaravelのプロジェクトを作成しようとすると以下のようなエラーが出ます.

> Crafting application... Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock
>   file Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - This package requires php >=7.0.0 but your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 2
>       - Installation request for doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0].
>       - doctrine/inflector v1.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 3
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.5.19 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.19].
>       - laravel/framework v5.5.19 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 4
>       - Installation request for swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 -> satisfiable by swiftmailer/swiftmailer[v6.0.2].
>       - swiftmailer/swiftmailer v6.0.2 requires php >=7.0.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 5
>       - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.1.1].
>       - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem
>   6
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.2.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.2.2].
>       - phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.2.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 7
>       - Installation request for phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-token-stream[2.0.1].
>       - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 8
>       - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.4.3].
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 9
>       - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 4.0.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[4.0.4].
>       - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 4.0.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 10
>       - Installation request for sebastian/comparator 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by sebastian/comparator[2.0.2].
>       - sebastian/comparator 2.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 11
>       - Installation request for sebastian/diff 2.0.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/diff[2.0.1].
>       - sebastian/diff 2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 12
>       - Installation request for sebastian/environment 3.1.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/environment[3.1.0].
>       - sebastian/environment 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 13
>       - Installation request for sebastian/exporter 3.1.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/exporter[3.1.0].
>       - sebastian/exporter 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 14
>       - Installation request for sebastian/global-state 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/global-state[2.0.0].
>       - sebastian/global-state 2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 15
>       - Installation request for sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3 -> satisfiable by sebastian/object-enumerator[3.0.3].
>       - sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 16
>       - Installation request for sebastian/object-reflector 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by sebastian/object-reflector[1.1.1].
>       - sebastian/object-reflector 1.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 17
>       - Installation request for sebastian/recursion-context 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/recursion-context[3.0.0].
>       - sebastian/recursion-context 3.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 18
>       - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.0].
>       - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 19
>       - laravel/framework v5.5.19 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - laravel/tinker v1.0.2 requires illuminate/console ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.19].
>       - Installation request for laravel/tinker v1.0.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v1.0.2].
>
> Application ready! Build something amazing.

Composerの方で指定した使用PHPのバージョンは`5.6`です.
以前`PHP7.0`を使用していたときにはこのようなエラーは出ませんでした.
調べてみたのですが解決できず、どうかお力添えください.
足りない箇所はお教えいただけると幸いです.

【keyword】
- Windows10
- PHP 5.6.32 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2017 16:00:49)
- Laravel Installer 1.4.1
- Composer version 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25

【追記】
Laravelのバージョンは`4.2.11`を使用したいと考えております.
Laravelはコマンドプロンプトから`Composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`と入力してインストールしています.

Comment: インストールしようとしてるLaravelのバージョンは何でしょうか？

Comment: @keitaro_so コメントありがとうございます！ 情報不足大変失礼いたしました. Laravelのバージョンは4.2.11を使用したいと考えております. Laravelはコマンドプロンプトからcomposer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"と入力してインストールしております.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ログを見る限りlaravel5.5がインストールされているように見えます。
php5.6を使用したいのならばlaravel5.4以前のものを入れないとだめそうですね。

composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist PROJECT_NAME 4.2.11

こんな感じのコマンドでインストールできないですかね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
ご提示頂いたコマンドを入力してみたのですが、やはり同じエラーが出てしまいました.
一度laravelをアンインストールしないといけないでしょうか...？
私事で恐れ入りますが、本日確認の時間が取れない為、明日改めて挑戦してみます.

Comment: ご提示頂いたコマンドを本日試してみましたところプロジェクトを作成することができました.
昨日はコマンドの意味を取り違えていて失敗してしまいましたが、このコマンド自体がプロジェクトを作成するコマンドだったと解り、解決することができました.
`laravel new PROJECT_NAME`ですと、常に最新のバージョンでLaravelのプロジェクトが作られるのですね.
しかし今度はPHPのバージョンが7.1になってしまうという問題が出てしまいましたので、別スレッドを立ててみたいと思います.
この度はありがとうございました！